# Strange performance of Outer

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra

The following takes 0.07 seconds on my laptop.

```
list1 = RandomReal[1.,1000000];
(Outer[Times, list1, RandomReal[1., 2]];) // AbsoluteTiming
```

But this takes 1.2 seconds:

```
list1 = RandomReal[1.,1000000];
(Outer[Times, list1, {1.,2.}];) // AbsoluteTiming
```

What is wrong here?

Both version 10.3 and 7 have this timing result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like `RandomReal[1., 2]` is automatically a packed array, whereas `{1., 2.}` is not. Notice;

```
(Outer[Times, list1, Developer`ToPackedArray@{1., 2.}];) // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.032425 *)
```

whereas

```
(Outer[Times, list1, {1., 2.}];) // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.542086 *)
```

Also:

```
list1 = Developer`FromPackedArray@RandomReal[1., 1000000];
(Outer[Times, list1, RandomReal[1., 2]];) // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.473775 *)
```

Packed arrays are good for both memory usage and for built-in *Mathematica* operations that are optimized for packed arrays (for instance). See [What is a packed array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array).

Comment: Oh, my god! So we users have to pay attention to this? It is ridiculous that using {1.,2.} should be careful :(

Comment: I am so disappointed with mathematica on this case

Comment: I think it's a consequence of *Mathematica*'s flexibility. `List`s can store any combination of data types, but packed arrays require that *Mathematica* *knows* that the data types are all the same and knows what that data type is. Therefore, you have to tell it that the list can be a packed array. Just like *any* programming language, you have to have a lot of experience and knowledge about the language in order to optimize your code, especially if you are running operations that are numerically intensive. IMO, *Mathematica* makes *basic* optimization pretty easy.

Comment: And in your referenced link "What is a packed array?" with 67 upvotes, I actually read it many times. while none of the answers tell me that use {1.,2.} should be careful.

Comment: I didn't know that either, but I think it's implicit in the statement "packed arrays can only contain objects of the same type, so mma does not need to keep track of the type of each element" and "Sparse arrays use packed arrays internally to store their data" (which are statements in two separate answers). But anyway, I have to stress that this sort of lack of transparency is not unique to *Mathematica* as a high-level language. There are many "black boxes", and something must be sacrificed for the trade-off of flexibility and new-user-friendliness.

Comment: I can't agree with you. Maybe I am too stupid. But I pay a lot of time using mathematica, and read many post on this site, and also read books. But I still amazed by this `Outer` result at first.  So I think mathematica could invent new symbols for numerical list, { } for general list, maybe [[[ ]]] for numerical list. This will solve all the pitfall, differentiate symbolic and numerical clearly, There will be no such stupid and strange timing result. What do you think? Actually I have this idea just month ago

Comment: @matheorem If you have read "What is a packed array?" many times, then surely you're aware that it is a key to explain differences speed and memory usage.  Surely it would be something to check when an issue with speed arises?  It always occurs to me....

Comment: @MichaelE2  Hi, MichaelE2 . You know what, I just haven't reached that level to aware of this immediately, the performance of mathematica is still weird to me often: )

Comment: @MichaelE2 I still have doubts, Why `{1., 2.} + RandomReal[1., {2, 10000000}]` has the same performance as `Developer`ToPackedArray[{1., 2.}] + 
   RandomReal[1., {2, 10000000}]`? According to your analysis, then I don't know how to explain this

Comment: @matheorem. Probably *Mathematica* knows to check if the output can be a packed array when one of the inputs is a packed array, and so in this case, it can tell that the data types are the same, and so it decides to make a packed array.

Comment: @march if so, then `Outer` should be damned...Why doesn't `Outer` check also?

Comment: A related question.  Given a list object is there any way to determine if it is stored as a packed array?

Comment: I think it's because `Plus` is `Listable` and if that attribute is applied first, the array would have to be unpacked; instead, there is a special case when one of the arguments is a packed array.  See Rob Knapp's talk (my comment under the what is a packed array question), or maybe it's discussed in one of the answers. Perhaps other functions could be made more efficient.

Comment: @JohnMcGee ``Developer`PackedArrayQ``

Comment: @march Thanks for the link to "What is a Packed Array?".

Comment: @MichaelE2 - of course! Thanks.

Comment: @matheorem `Outer` is compilable. From your comments it sounds like you would prefer the behavior of, for example, `outerTimes = Compile[{{l1, _Real, 1}, {l2, _Real, 1}}, Outer[Times, l1, l2]]`.

Comment: @Karsten7. Thank you. It seems that this compilation simply force Outer to check the type of input. So this is the question I asked in previous comment. Why doesn't Outer add a check process?