# Why are so many built-in numerical function doesn't check its argument is packed array or not?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, packed-arrays

This question is brought by [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100687/4742).

```
Outer[Times, RandomReal[1., 1000000], {1., 2.}];
```

is much slower than

```
Outer[Times, RandomReal[1., 1000000], RandomReal[1., 2]];
```

because {1.,2.} is not packed array. The same problem also exists in `Dot`.

So a natural question is why so many built-in numerical function doesn't check its arguments to see if they are packed array or not? And transform all the unpacked to packed array? Because, `PackedArrayQ` and `ToPackedArray` don't take too much time.

Here is test

```
In[111]:= list = RandomReal[1., 1000000];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[list] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[112]= {1.81124*10^-6, True}
```

so `PackedArrayQ` is fast for list that are already packed.

```
In[113]:= list[[1]] = aaa;
Developer`PackedArrayQ[list] // AbsoluteTiming
Developer`ToPackedArray[list]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[114]= {0.020944, False}

Out[115]= {3.62249*10^-6, Null}
```

if there is an element changed to symbol, `PackedArrayQ` is slower, but still pretty fast. And although perform `ToPackedArray` doesn't change anything, it does no harm, for it almost doesn't take time.

```
In[116]:= list[[1]] = 1.;
Developer`PackedArrayQ[list] // AbsoluteTiming
Developer`ToPackedArray[list]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[117]= {1.81124*10^-6, False}

Out[118]= {0.0126244, Null}
```

If a list is all composed of machine number, `PackedArrayQ` is fast, while `ToPackedArray` is slower now, but again pretty fast for a list of 1000000 elements.

In conclusion, If built-in function first check all its argument's packedness and then convert all to packed array, this will not take too much time. For a 1000000 list, it takes at most 0.02 sec, and for {1.,2.} is the first example, negligible!. But the performance boost that packed array brings is huge. **Then why mathematica doesn't do it?**

---

PS. I'd also like to hear more comments why `{1., 2.} + RandomReal[1., {2, 10000000}]` doesn't suffer the problem of packedness?

---

**update**

I'd like to update a great illustration that showing how Packing and unpacking many times still brings performance boost. This shows add Packing will not harm the performance, **welcome any counterexample**

```
In[87]:= Outer[Times, RandomReal[1., 2], 
   Developer`FromPackedArray@
    RandomReal[1., 1000000]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[87]= {0.99861, Null}
```

and this one

```
In[86]:= Outer[Times, RandomReal[1., 2], 
   Developer`ToPackedArray@
    Developer`FromPackedArray@
     Developer`ToPackedArray@
      Developer`FromPackedArray@
       Developer`ToPackedArray@
        Developer`FromPackedArray@
         Developer`ToPackedArray@
          Developer`FromPackedArray@
           RandomReal[1., 1000000]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[86]= {0.536909, Null}
```

Comment: Perhaps someone from Wolfram support can advise us why they made *Mathematica* the way they made it.  Shouldn't you suggest to the company ways to improve the product?

Comment: @MichaelE2  Yesterday , I was about to directly ask wolfram for the `Outer` problem, because I thought that maybe a bug. But it turns out that it is not. So I think should ask here first, because I think people here may already know the answer : )

Comment: @MichaelE2 and I know there are wolfram staff on this site : )

Comment: there is overhead in packing arrays so the list needs to be a minimum length to justify packing otherwise it is inefficient. The cut offs for many different functions are specified in system options which you will be able to find on this site but from memory lists under 200-250 in length will not be packed automatically because of the overhead involved. As always there are some exceptions to consider but getting back to your problem you should not expect to type `{1.,2.}` and have it automatically packed.

Comment: ** exception include functions like `Range` and `RandomReal` which will produce packed arrays even for lists of short lengths.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Hi, MikeHoneychurch.  Could you show some examples on "overhead in packing arrays" so we can understand it more clearly?

Comment: `Timing@{1.,2.}` and `Timing@Developer`ToPackedArray@{1.,2.}`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch So just this? But this is what my post have analyzed, the kind of overhead is negligible compared to the performance boost that packing bring to us. Anyway, you mentioned `SystemOptions`. I found there is an option `"PackedArrayOptions" -> "ListableAutoPackLength"`, but setting this to `1` doesn't change the performance of `Outer[Times, RandomReal[1., 1000000], {1., 2.}]`. So this is not useful, and another question what cases will this options can affect?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch BTW, `Timing@{1.,2.}` and `Timing@DeveloperToPackedArray@{1.,2.}` both gives `0.` time on my computer, so the overhead doesn't exist completely in this case

Comment: @matheorem I believe, the general answer is that it may be hard to predict all possible cases where it makes sense to pack arrays and it may be hard to pick the right algorithm to do it efficiently. E.g. `Do[someFunction[packedarray, unpackedarray],{i,1000}]` raises the questions: is `unpackedarray` dependent on `i`? Can it be packed first or does it have to be packed each time the `Do` loop loops? etc; etc; etc...

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Hi, LLlAMnYP, thank you for comment. But I think your concern and example is not strong. Because in my post I have done analysis, though packing an unpackedarray takes time, but the performance boost is much greater. And this is not relavent to whether the function is in `Do` loop or not. If it is in the do loop, we just pack it every loop, there is no problem, we still get greater performance boost the same as no loop

Comment: That's exactly my point. Say, `someFunc[packed, unpacked]` is faster without packing, but `Do[someFunc[packed[i], unpacked], {i, 1000}]` is faster if you prepack `unpacked` ONCE before invoking the loop, but slower if you pack it every time the loop loops. Now the analysis of whether to pack `unpacked` and whether it must be done inside the loop or once before the loop will itself be a huge hurdle.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Still can't agree with you : )  But I understand what you mean now. Of course, if we could prepack the unpacked, surely it is the best way. But your assumption "slower if you pack it every time the loop loops" is not tenable. Since you didn't give an explicit example that packing will not boost while on the other hand slow down the execution. But I already has the `Outer` example. To be explicit, let us try this (to be continued)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP see my update of post

Comment: I have run a few tests, and it does so seem, that even when you have `Outer` of two lists of length 2, packed arrays are so efficient, that packing then doing `Outer` is more efficient, than just doing it as is. I guess it's always a good idea to pack then.

Comment: Quick code dump: ``a = RandomReal[1., 2]; b = ToPackedArray[{1., 2.}]; <<Developer` Do[Outer[Times, {1., 2.}, a], {1000000}]; // AbsoluteTiming; Do[Outer[Times, b, a], {1000000}] // AbsoluteTiming; Do[Outer[Times, ToPackedArray[{1., 2.}], 
   a], {1000000}] // AbsoluteTiming`` One sees, that the unpacked array is slowest, then comes the loop with `ToPackedArray`, then with the prepacked `b`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Using `RepeatedTiming` shows on my computer. Packing is 0.980sec and unpack is 0.931, only 5%, not a strong counterexample at all : )

Comment: Try it with a symbolic `g` instead of a special case, optimized head like `Times`: ``With[{array2 = Developer`FromPackedArray@RandomReal[1., 1000000]}, Outer[g, {1., x}, Developer`ToPackedArray@array2]; // RepeatedTiming]`` -- 30% longer than without packing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a request for an enhancement to _Mathematica_ and it thus not admissible to this site.

Comment: @m_goldberg If I changed my title as "Is there any practical example showing that Packing list will harm the performance significantly?". Will this still off topic?

Comment: Regardless of the possible implied meaning, this is a useful discussion that gives insights on improving performance of code. I would not vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

More of an extended comment, but I have found a single counterexample, where it's longer to pack, than to just do it.

Edit: of course this needs `` <<Developer` `` first.

```
Do[Outer[Times, ToPackedArray[{3.}], ToPackedArray[{5.}]], {1000000}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.62244, Null} *)

Do[Outer[Times, {3.}, {5.}], {1000000}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.929396, Null} *)
```

Of course the silly case of an outer product of lists of length one will hardly be useful anywhere.

Comment: I have to say this is far from practical case...